# Can I use Colorbox on images, when there is no anchor tag

Tags: jquery, anchor, colorbox, image, ektron

I'm trying to create a slidewhow with Colorbox.  Unfortunately, I have no control over how the images are created, so I can't put anchor tags, or rel= on the images.

The best I can do, is something like this:

```
<div id="cbImg" class="slideshow">
    <img src="file1.png" />    
    <img src="file2.png" />
    <img src="file3.png" />
    <img src="file4.png" />
</div>
```

The image tags will could have height, width and alt tags... but it's dynamically generated.  All I can control is the DIV tag surrounding the images.  There may or may not be other tags (p, div, span) surrounding the images.

I want something like this:

```
<div id="cbImg" class="slideshow">
    <a href="file1.png" rel="slide" class="pop"><img src="file1.png" /></a>
    <a href="file2.png" rel="slide" class="pop"><img src="file2.png" /></a>
    <a href="file3.png" rel="slide" class="pop"><img src="file3.png" /></a>
    <a href="file4.png" rel="slide" class="pop"><img src="file4.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Yes, this is coming out of a CMS... no, I can't modify how it renders.  I'm trying to make a slideshow (if possible).

Comment: Do you mean "The image tags should have height, width and alt tags"? Are you interested in modifying how it renders? Ektron has a couple of options on this.

Comment: No, I can get the height/width stuff.  I needed anchor tags around the image... but the images are added in a Blog post within the Ektron Workarea...  I ended up using JQuery and dynamically adding my anchor tags that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I ended up using JQuery to create the anchor tags around the IMG tag dynamically... which then let me add the class and rel= I needed to use the ColorBox option.

Here is one of the answers I used for tips on how to create the anchor tags:

[jQuery: Easiest way to wrap an image tag with an A anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767414/jquery-easiest-way-to-wrap-an-image-tag-with-an-a-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be via XSLT transforming the blog article. However, if the images are inside the blog post content, this would not be easy (especially as Ektron uses XSLT 1.0, which does not have regex support).

If you wanted to do this server side, you'd probably have to get the content and do a string replace. Alternatively you could take your jQuery solution and use NodeJS to run it server side.

Comment: True... I looked at that briefly... yet my XSLT skills are lacking, and this is only for a short period of time (about a month).  I couldn't justify spending more time learning XSLT for something only used for a few weeks.