# Getting facebook photos in one json request with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json, facebook

Okay, so I have a "page" on Facebook as well as its own website. I want to link all photos from the "page" to the website so I can have one gallery to edit. I know how to receive one image but I do not know how to receive more than one then display it in, lets say, a new div? I have googled the !@#$ out of this and still have came up with nothing.. Thanks in advance :D

```
var fburl_photo = "http://graph.facebook.com/868.Rotary.Northstar.RCACS/albums?fields=photos";
$.getJSON(fburl_photo,function(data){
    var albums = data["picture"];
    $("#albums").append("<div>" + albums + "</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. Just let me know if anything is unclear.

```
var url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/';
url += '868.Rotary.Northstar.RCACS/albums?fields=photos'; 
//to save some space here

$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){

            $.each(data.data, function(k1, album){

                if(k1 > 1) //just showing the first 2lists for demo purpose
                    return true; //skipping the rest

                var pictureArray = album.photos.data;
                //get an array of photos                    

                $.each(pictureArray, function(k2, pictureObject){

                //pictureObject.picture contains the image url

                //create a new image tag and append it to the body

                    var $img = $('<img/>')
                                   .prop({ src: pictureObject.picture })
                                   .wrap('<a href="#anchor"></a>')
                                   .appendTo('body');

                });

            });

        }
    });

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gVZuC/

Comment: Now if i wanted to put an anchor on each img to its source... how would I append that?

Comment: @CantFindIt Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767414/jquery-easiest-way-to-wrap-an-image-tag-with-an-a-anchor-tag

Comment: url += '868.Rotary.Northstar.RCACS/albums?fields=photos'; ??

 what is this i am not understanding. 

can i used this type

url +=  'me/albums?fields=photos'

Comment: @TrilokGupta It's just merging the strings together