# Disabling and enabling links using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

(By disable I mean remove the links without removing their contents and then enable - to retrieve the links)

I've read about wrap and replacewith, bind and unbind. But I can't seem to get it to work. Basically I have a button which I click in order to disable/enable the links. Here is the code I've worked so far:

```
var edit = false;
$('.courselink').click(function(e){ //the links
if(edit == true){
    return false;
}
});

$('.vieweditlink').click(function(){ //This is the button

    if($(this).html() == 'Edit'){
        $(this).html('View');
        edit = true;
    }
    else {
        $(this).html('Edit');
        edit = false;
     }
 });
```

Everything is in `$(document).ready` of course

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ugkc8gsd/7/

Comment: Show and hide them, don't disable them. The reason you can't seem to disable them is because that's not what links are supposed to do.

Comment: @CBauer Thanks, but please enlighten me. How am I going to do that? Hehe

Comment: Tell me specific what you are trying to achive because I don't understand what you exactly want. Maybe create a jsfiddle.

Comment: e.preventDefault will stop the link from running, so all you need to do is change the return false to e.preventDefault()

Comment: @BenPotter I've tried that already. It didn't work

Comment: personally I think there is something else wrong. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @VRC I want to remove the link from the content. http://jsfiddle.net/ugkc8gsd/

Comment: @charlietflhttp://jsfiddle.net/ugkc8gsd/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that anyone is interested, but here's how I solved the problem:

```
var edit = false;
var links = $('.courselink').toArray(); //this gets the links but not the whole elements


$('.vieweditlink').click(function(){

if($(this).html() == 'Edit'){
    $(this).html('View');
    edit = true;

    $('.courselink').each(function(i) {
        $(this).replaceWith("<div class='courselink'>"+$(this).html()+"</div>");
    });
}
else {
    $(this).html('Edit');
    edit = false;

    $('.courselink').each(function(i) {
        $(this).replaceWith("<a class='courselink' href='"+links[i]+"'>"+$(this).html()+"</a>");
    });
}
});
```

If anyone knows a better solution, please feel free to share! Thanks!

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/13tudb3p/**

Comment: Ooh I get what you wanted. You should've said u didn't want them to be anchors anymore. Anyway this solution seems working good for u. Although ur if is kinda weird since u don't use the edit variable you declare in the beginning. You do the replace of the text which make it kinda double. You could also just create new div or anchors instead of replacing but I dunno what is better for u project. Good u found a solution tho. Next time describe it a bit better ;)

Comment: @VRC hi! Just saw your comment. Yup it kinda makes it double but it's fine. I just had to tweak my CSS so it looks the same :) And I didn't have to remove the anchors, really, but the solution you gave me didn't work out, so.. Hehe but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Still not so sure what you exactly are trying to achive but to hide links you just hide them.
http://jsfiddle.net/ugkc8gsd/8/

Hide them in the click event button

```
$('.vieweditlink').click(function () 
{
    $('.courselink').hide();
});
```

**Edit** : Ooh I see u edited your post. 
Well here is a new jsfiddle  
http://jsfiddle.net/ugkc8gsd/10/ 
Hope it helps

**Edit 2** :
Here is the new promised jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ugkc8gsd/12/
Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Nope. I don't want to hide the whole link. The contents inside the link should remain.

Comment: What do you mean with the contents inside the link should remain? The html is still the same but it just isn't visible

Comment: I mean the "Some content" should still be visible. The only difference is that the "Some content" shouldn't act as a link. The result should be something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767414/jquery-easiest-way-to-wrap-an-image-tag-with-an-a-anchor-tag) OMG sorry if I'm not making myself clear :(

Comment: ooh I think I get what you want. The link should work normally. when you click on the button 'edit' then the "somecontent" text should still be visible but the click shouldn't be working. Like that?

Comment: Yup! Exactly! Thank you

Comment: hahah I explained it in just one line xD. No offense but describing isn't your best quality :P. Anyway I will make a new jsfiddle for ya. Gimmie a few mints

Comment: Haha no offense taken! I know that myself. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunately though, this did not work for my code. The links are still clickable.

Comment: Then there is something different or you didn't implement it right. Look at my last jsfiddle 12. That one is working as how u described

Comment: I don't know haha. It seems to be working in the JSFiddle, but I figured maybe JSFiddle doesn't allow links (or allows it only if its target's blank!)

Answer (score 0):

To make the links invisible when they are disabled...

http://jsfiddle.net/6q7dr9fq/3/

```
$('.courselink').click(function(e){ //the links
    $('.courselink:hidden').show();

    $(this).hide();
});
```